# Is update an idempotent request in REST API for below scenario?

Tags: java, rest, http

Say a hypothetical scenario in which Rest API is being used to update the number of steps for a person in the database. So ideally, step count should always be increasing.

HTTP_PUT: [http://www.example.com/{person}/{steps}](http://www.example.com/%7Bperson%7D/%7Bsteps%7D)

Say tracker-1 updates the steps to count=10 and then tracker-2 to count=15 in the database. Now let's say tracker-1 sends another update request to update count=10. It would update the count to 10 from 15. For now, let's assume there is no check before writing to DB that count should greater than the existing value. Second request by tracker-1 produces the same result as its first request.

My questions are:

1. Is this a scenario of an idempotent request?
2. Which should be a better option for this scenario, PUT or POST?

Answer (score 0):

Idempotent means you can call method many times without altering the result. Calling put several times asking it to increase count to 10, will keep it as 10 no matter how many times you call it (that same put) - that is why it is idempotent. POST is not idempotent by definition. It is always better to use PUT for update, POST should only be used for creation.